# Probability of nobody being born in a specific month

Tags: mathematics, probability

> Assume 11 persons are born in 11 different months. What is the probability $P(n)$ that none of them is born in the $n$-th month?

This would be pretty easy if all months had the same length, then $P(n)$ would be $\tfrac{1}{12}$ for all months. It gets interesting when one considers that different months have different length.

**Assumptions:**

- The probability to be born on a specific day is the same for all days.

  In the time span all these peole are born February has 28¼ days on average. (This would not be the case, if these people could have been born in 1900.)

**Bonus:** Find a way of avoiding a brute-force summation over all possibilities.

> I'm asking this question because people seem to be stuck at one part of [another question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56543/the-most-probable-key). I thought, instead of adding a hint there, it would be more fun to outsource it into a separate question. As both questions are now linked, people can use the result of this question, which should work almost the same as providing a hint.

Comment: I don't think "The probability to be born on a specific day is the same for all days." is a very good assumption to model reality. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose the month lengths are $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{12}$, and the probability of nobody being born in month $i$ as in the question statement is $P_i$ for $1\le i\le12$.

Let the probability of an arbitrary $10$ people being born randomly around the year being born in all months except $i$ and $j$ with $i\ne j$ given that they are in $10$ different months be $Q_{\{i,j\}}$ (same problem with $10$ months).

Notice that for all $i\ne j$, $P_i:P_j=\frac{a_j}{a_i+a_j}:\frac{a_i}{a_i+a_j}=a_j:a_i$, since  $P_i=Q_{\{i,j\}}\cdot\frac{a_j}{a_i+a_j}$ and $P_j=Q_{\{i,j\}}\cdot\frac{a_i}{a_i+a_j}$.

Let $X=a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{12}$.

Then $P_1:P_2:\dots:P_{12}=\frac{X}{a_1}:\frac{X}{a_2}:\dots:\frac{X}{a_{12}}$.

Now, since $P_1+P_2+\dots+P_{12}=1$, for $1\le i\le12$:
$$P_i=\frac{\frac{X}{a_i}}{\frac{X}{a_1}+\frac{X}{a_2}+\ldots+\frac{X}{a_{12}}}=\frac{\frac{1}{a_i}}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_{12}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{a_i\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_{12}}\right)}$$

Now in our case, the year, these probabilities turn out to be about (according to Python 3.6):

1. 0.08176161304326855
2. 0.089720708118277
3. 0.08176161304326855
4. 0.08448700014471083
5. 0.08176161304326855
6. 0.08448700014471083
7. 0.08176161304326855
8. 0.08176161304326855
9. 0.08448700014471083
10. 0.08176161304326855
11. 0.08448700014471083
12. 0.08176161304326855

Code:

```
x=[31,28.25,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
y=sum([1/i for i in x])
for i in x:print(1/i/y)
```

Comment: Perfect. A well-done derivation that doesn't need a brute-force summation. I can confirm the final formula as well as the numbers.

Comment: Not that I disagree with the answer, but I'm confused by the derivation. Shouldn't P(n) simply be the number of days in month n divided by the number of days in a year?

Comment: $P_n$ is not the chance that if we choose an random date in the year, it falls in month $n$ but rather if we choose 11 random dates in the year that none fall in month $n$ given that they all fall in different months. @Xenocacia

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Apologies. I answered a different question. I thought $P(n)$ was the probability that a twelfth person would be born in the $n$th month.

As defined, the probability $P(n)$ is:

\begin{eqnarray}
P(n)&=&\left(\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{12}d_i}{d_n((d_2\cdots d_{12})+(d_1\cdot d_3\cdots d_{12})+\cdots+(d_1\cdots d_{11}))}\right) \\
&=&\frac{1}{d_n}\left(\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{d_{12}}\right)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}

---

Answer for my (wrong) understanding of $P(n)$:

The summations will, I think, all cancel out. So $P(n)=\frac{1}{12}$ regardless of the length of the month.

Surely not, I hear you say.

Suppose we have 3 months will length $a$, $b$, and $c$. What's $P(n=3)$?

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{ab}{ab+ac+bc}\right)\left(\frac{c}{a+b+c}\right)=\left(\frac{abc}{(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)}\right)
\end{equation}

This quantity will be the same regardless, so once you normalize it, will come out equal.

The same basic equation will work for any number of months. The probability $P(n)$ will be the product of two components:

- The probability that you're in a situation where the other eleven people are born in months that are not $n$, which will be proportional to the product of the number of days in each of those months. That is, proportional to $d_1\cdot d_2\cdots d_{n-1}\cdot d_{n+1}\cdots d_{12}$, where $d_k$ is the number of days in month $k$
- The probability of the twelfth person being born in the $n$th month, which will be proportional to $d_n$.

The product of these two will be the product of all the days of the month ($\prod_{i=1}^{12}d_i$) which is independent of $n$.

Comment: In order to argue against this, I need to understand what these fractions (e.g. $\frac{ab}{ab+ac+bc}$) in the simplified case of 3 months mean. Could you please comment on that?

Comment: Suppose I had two months of length 1 and 2. The probability of a person not being born in month 1 is 2/3, and the probability of a person not being born in month 2 is 1/3. How does your argument fail for this simplified case?

Comment: Oh, I might have answered a different question. I thought P(n) was the probability that a twelfth person would be born in the nth month.